# Installed from source code, but when checking installed-version, it's showing old-version. How to reslove?

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm

OS: Fedora 12, x86_64

```
[root@earth]# rpm -qa cmake
cmake-2.6.4-5.fc12.x86_64
```

But I installed `cmake-3.2.3` from source code.

How to check installed version that is installed from source code?
How to update the package version to system?

But

```
[root@earth]# cmake --version
cmake version 3.2.3

[root@earth]# /usr/local/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.2.3
```

Comment: where did you install cmake (from source) ? What is the output of `which cmake` ? What is the output of `cmake --version` . You can remove the rpm installed package `rpm -e package-name` Is your cmake-3.2.3 in your path ?

Comment: `[root@earth]# cmake --version ` outputs `cmake version 3.2.3`

Comment: How to find the installation-path?

Comment: And also  `[root@earth]# /usr/local/bin/cmake --version` outputs `cmake version 3.2.3`

Comment: cool, so you are running the version you want. So just remove the package as I have shown you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you installed from source code (I'm guessing with `./configure; make; make install`), the RPMDB (RPM database) didn't get updated, so RPM thinks you still ahve the old version installed. If you want RPM to know about the new version, find an RPM of the new version (or make one) and install it with RPM (`rpm -i`).

Comment: You are correct. I did the same. Is there any way to update RPMDB without RPMs?

Comment: No, not any practical way.